# find out dokuwiki version without administrative privileges

Tags: dokuwiki

I have access to a dokuwiki as user without administrative rights only. Is there any way to find out which version I'm using, e.g. with an [action mode](https://www.dokuwiki.org/devel%3aaction_modes) passed in URL? I want to do further research on available action modes for my version and without knowing the version it's almost impossible to ask useful questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [Official FAQ](https://www.dokuwiki.org/faq%3aversion), version information is restricted to admins for security reasons. As an admin, you would see the version in the Admin panel or by going to `doku.php?do=check`.